# Retrieve distinct element value from a List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Animal>` , which contains 100s of objects. There'll be a field which is `AnimalType` that will be common. I need to fetch 
this value.

```
            List<Animal> foundAnimal = db.Animals
                .Where(a => a.Name == "Elephant"
                    )).ToList();
```

The `foundAnimal` object has a element called `AnimalType` (Which is an `int`) which is the same for all "Elephants". I need to retrieve this value from the above
List.

How can I do that ?

**Animal object**

```
private string Name {get;set}
private int Age{get;set}
private int AnimalType{get;set}
```

What I tried:

```
var ani = foundAnimal.Distinct();
```

But the above gives me a list of Distinct Animal objects. What I need to know is the value that is common in the Animal Object (for the name Elephant) 
which is a `int` value.

UPDATE

```
new Animal {Name = "Elephant" , Age 12 , AnimalType = 1 } 
new Animal {Name = "Elephant" , Age 12 , AnimalType = 1 } 
new Animal {Name = "Elephant" , Age 12 , AnimalType = 1 } 
new Animal {Name = "Ant" , Age 12 , AnimalType = 2 } 
new Animal {Name = "Ant" , Age 12 , AnimalType = 2 } 
new Animal {Name = "Elephant" , Age 12 , AnimalType = 1 } 
new Animal {Name = "Elephant" , Age 12 , AnimalType = 1 } 
new Animal {Name = "Elephant" , Age 12 , AnimalType = 1 }
```

The list will give me Animals where Name is Elephant

```
List<Animal> foundAnimal = db.Animals
            .Where(a => a.Name == "Elephant"
                )).ToList();
```

The above Will return Only Objects where the Name is equal to Elephant.

All what I need is to get the `AnimalType` which is `1` when Name == Elephant.

Hope I was able to explain this clearly.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I have updated my post. Please have a look.